# ncurses program crashes on anything other than PuTTY

Tags: c, ncurses

I have an older ncurses-based program that does some simple IO on a few files (i.e.: setup program). However, from a terminal different from PuTTY, it crashes with SIGBUS

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x00000000004028b1 in fDisplay (ptr=Variable "ptr" is not available.
) at file_cpy.c:676
676             sprintf(p, " %-36s ", (*ptr)->datainfo.option);
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000004028b1 in fDisplay (ptr=Variable "ptr" is not available.
) at file_cpy.c:676
#1  0x0000000000402cdb in fredraw (c=0x7fffffffe860) at file_cpy.c:696
#2  0x0000000000401996 in ls_dispatch (c=0x2020202020202020) at ds_cell.c:324
#3  0x0000000000403bf2 in main_dir (c=0x2020202020202020) at file_cpy.c:811
#4  0x0000000000403cb3 in main () at file_cpy.c:1345
(gdb) x/i $pc
0x4028b1 <fDisplay+17>: mov    (%rax),%rdx
(gdb)
```

This happens on Linux and FreeBSD, regardless of ncurses version and 32/64bit architecture. I'm completely stumped.

fDisplay() is called here:

```
/*
 * File redraw routine. Draws current list on screen.
 */
int fredraw (CELL * c)
{
        register int row = c->srow;
        dlistptr p = c->list_start;
        int i = 0;
        char buff[200];
        if (c->ecol - c->scol)
                sprintf(buff, "%*s",c->ecol - c->scol + 1, " ");
        while (i <= c->erow - c->srow && p != NULL)
        {
                if (p == c->current) wattron(c->window,A_REVERSE);
                        mvaddstr (row , c->scol, fDisplay(&p));
                if (p == c->current) wattroff(c->window,A_REVERSE);
                        row++; i++;
                p = p->nextlistptr;
        }
        if (row <= c -> erow)
                for (; row <= c -> erow ; row++)
                        mvaddstr(row, c->scol, buff);
        wrefresh(c->window);
        c -> redraw = FALSE;
        return TRUE;
}
```

fredraw() is called here:

```
int main_dir(CELL *c) {
int i;

        getcwd(current_path, sizeof(current_path));
        strcat(current_path, "/.config.h");
        load_file(current_path);

        c->keytable = file_cpy_menu;
        c->func_table = file_cpy_table;
        c->ListEntryProc = File_Entry;
        c->UpdateStatusProc = status_update;
        c->redraw = TRUE;
        c->ListExitProc = List_Exit;
        c->ListPaintProc = fredraw;

        c->srow = 3;
        c->scol = 1;
        c->erow = c->window->_maxy - 5;
        c->ecol = c->window->_maxx - 1;
        c->max_rows = c->window->_maxy;
        c->max_cols = c->window->_maxx;

        c->filename = "[ Config ]";
        c->menu_bar = 0;
        c->normcolor = 0x07;
        c->barcolor = 0x1f;
        init_dlist(c);
        for (i = 0; config_type[i].option; i++)
                insert_fdlist(c, &config_type[i]);


        /*
        * Go Do It
        */
        do {
                c->redraw = TRUE;
                ls_dispatch(c);
        } while (c->termkey != ESC && c->termkey != ALT_X);
        return TRUE;
}
```

Finally, main() calls the above functions:

```
int main() {
    CELL file_cpy = {0};
    WINDOW *mainwin;
    mainwin = initscr();
    start_color();
    setup_colors();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(mainwin, TRUE);
    meta(mainwin, TRUE);
    raw();

    leaveok(mainwin, TRUE);
    wbkgd(mainwin, COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_MAIN));
    wattron(mainwin, COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_MAIN));
    werase(mainwin);
    refresh();

    file_cpy.window = mainwin;

    main_dir(&file_cpy);

    wbkgd(mainwin, A_NORMAL);
    werase(mainwin);
    echo();
    nocbreak();
    noraw();
    refresh();
    endwin();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What does PuTTY set `$TERM` to? What if you change `$TERM` to that value in a non-PuTTY environment? And what about terminal size?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your problem. I remember that I once had to write a game-board program using C and ncurses, but they specifically told us to ONLY use Putty as our shell instead of any other type of shell program.

Comment: Kevin, $TERM is set to xterm by putty and my other application. Could this be an issue with ncurses?

Comment: It seems this isn't specific to anything other than my emulator for my client. PuTTY works fine.

Comment: I doubt we will be really able to help you if you don't paste more code. Especially, where does `ptr` come from?

Comment: I added all of the functions, I hope this helps!

Comment: The indentation inside the loop in `fredraw` is not uniform. Should `mvaddstr` be called if the condition is true, or all the time in the loop? Could you be missing some curly braces (`{` and `}`) around the statements in the `if`?

Comment: Are both terminals the same size?

Comment: Craig: No. PuTTy is a small size, (it's default) and others are full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are calling `main_dir` and `ls_dispatch` with a pointer `c` initialized to `0x2020202020202020`. While not *completely* impossible, I find it very unlikely, and it looks to me as if you're **overwriting** the pointer with spaces.

`valgrind` would probably help, or some kind of memory or stack protection check.

Why this depends on the terminal, I could not say; possibly there's some TERM-depending code (such as "allocate as many rows as there are on screen"). Anyway, that is not the bug: it's only the *condition* bringing the bug in the open. This kind of error is usually caused by a hard-wired constant which sometimes is exceeded by the real value (in the example above I could say "allocate 96 rows", assuming that *96 rows will always be enough for everyone*; whereas a TERM with 100 rows would foil the assumption and lead to a buffer overrun).

It might also be an artifact of the debugger, seeing as how `c` is allocated on the stack (but I don't think so: it should be `c=0x7fffsomething` - at least on the systems where I checked) . Anyway, I'd repeat the test like this, by making `file_cpy` heap dynamic:

```
int main() {
    CELL *file_cpy = NULL;
    WINDOW *mainwin;

    file_cpy = malloc(sizeof(CELL));

    ...

    file_cpy->window = mainwin;

    main_dir(file_cpy);

    ...
    free(file_cpy); // file_cpy = NULL; // we immediately return
    return TRUE;
```

and then I'd try and tabulate the pointer's value throughout the `main_dir` function, in case it's overwritten.